# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I tried to send an SMS via my platform but I get this error :

**Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:146)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:966)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:56)**

the error is at this level :

```
 CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

`HttpGet httpGet = null;

    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;

    HttpEntity entity = null;</pre>`

Comment: Have a look at this [httpclient main java lang nosuchfielderror instance at org.apache.http.conn.ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868242/httpclient-main-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-instance-at-org-apache-http-conn-s)  theres also a "possible duplicate" link that might help.  Also doesnt look like you have any pertinent code listed, e.g. I dont see you doing anything with the httpclient

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTPClient "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868242/httpclient-main-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-instance-at-org-apache-http-conn-s)

Comment: Summarized: your runtime classpath is messed up with duplicate different versioned libraries.