# "Android Private Libraries" doesn't appear in project

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

The "Android Private Libraries" item is missing from my project (it doesn't appear in the Project Explorer in Eclipse)...
It appears as though it isn't getting built into the project either, as I'm getting various errors regarding jar files in my "libs" folder...

It does appear in Java Build Path (yet it appears to be empty - no jar files appear under it in the Libraries tab), though, and I did make sure it is checked there.

If it is of any relevance, the project at hand has a lot of Android library project dependencies as well, and in those library projects the jar files under libs/ do appear under Android Private Libraries.

Comment: May be you could have posted screenshot of eclipse, so people can answer well

Comment: I'm posting this from my phone... I'll post a screenshot as soon as I can.

Answer (score 11):

I found the problem - I just recently added a new library project as a dependency, and it had an earlier version of android-support-v4.jar in its Android Private Libraries than the one I was using, so that ended up causing the entire Android Private Libraries folder not to be generated in the end project.

Found this out by looking at the Android Console after trying to build.

Comment: @saarraz1 Cheers !! thanks. I deleted support library then it works

Answer (score 10):

May be try the following steps

- Check and install Android SDK Build-tools in Android SDK Manager.
- `Package Explorer -> Right click the project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties`.
- `Project -> Clean`
- Check this [Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

Please update question with eclipse screen shot to get more clarity on problem you face :)

Answer (score 1):

1. check console
2. you can find android-support-v4.jar in two paths
3. Go to those path manually and replace the android-support-v4.jar with larger size

> thats it!!it works for me:-)

Answer (score 0):

this question is duplicated with [Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

Firstly, you may need to check out our "Problems" view in eclipse for any useful information there. In my issue, it said that two versions of android-support-v4.jar were found in workspace. this error prevented the importation of private libraries. Issue was fixed after I removed one of the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I removed android-support-v4.jar from java build path in properties and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the oldest jar file from the libs folder and replace it with the same jar file that's being referenced in the other project. If they both have the same version it should work and you should see your Android Private Libraries folder again.