# Why application stopped unexpectedly?

Tags: android

This is just used for create lab layout. When I run this stop running and show me a dialog box on emulator screen which say, application stopped unexpectedly. I not able to find error in code through reading code. I register all of my activities in manifest. Can somebody please tell me what is error in this code.

Here, this is my main Activity class-

```
package com.example.tabwithswipe;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Initilization
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
actionBar = getActionBar();
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

// Adding Tabs
for (String tab_name : tabs) {
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
        .setTabListener(this));
}

/**
* on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
* */
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // on changing the page
    // make respected tab selected
    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
}
});
}

 @Override
 public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
 }

 @Override
 public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
 // on tab selected
 // show respected fragment view
 viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
 }

 @Override
 public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
 }

 }
```

Here is my logcat:

```
03-12 14:37:48.851: I/dalvikvm(494): Failed resolving Lcom/example/tabwithswipe/MainActivity; interface 8 'Landroid/app/ActionBar$TabListener;'
03-12 14:37:48.902: W/dalvikvm(494): Link of class 'Lcom/example/tabwithswipe/MainActivity;' failed
03-12 14:37:48.902: D/AndroidRuntime(494): Shutting down VM
03-12 14:37:48.931: W/dalvikvm(494): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tabwithswipe/com.example.tabwithswipe.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.tabwithswipe.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.tabwithswipe-1.apk]
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.tabwithswipe.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.tabwithswipe-1.apk]
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
03-12 14:37:48.992: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  ... 11 more
03-12 14:38:08.451: I/Process(494): Sending signal. PID: 494 SIG: 9`
```

Here is TabPagerAdapter class:

```
package com.example.tabwithswipe;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
 super(fm);
} 

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return new TopRatedFragment();


    case 1: 
        return new GamesFragment();

    case 2:
        return new MoviesFragment();

    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3;
}
}
```

Comment: seems like you've forgot to add your activity in manifest

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/16596990/2001247, this is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your Manifest file :

```
<activity android:name="com.example.tabwithswipe.MainActivity>       
</activity>
```

Comment: Are you using any external jar file?

Comment: Where I can check about these external jar files

Comment: In your project's, libs folder.