# Android Google Maps GeoPoint issue

Tags: android, google-maps

I know it's have been asked several time, but in all answers, i don't find solution so I come to ask myself.

In an Activity named "DeAs" I have an adress editText, and I want to display a list of potential adress below the editText the user is editing.

So first in the Android Manifest, I've wrote this:

```
<activity android:name=".DeAs">
        <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </activity>
```

I've transform my build.gradle to load Google API:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22'
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.fabien.rh"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

I have declared a Listener on my editText:

```
adressete = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.daadressete);

        adressete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                new SearchClicked(adressete.getText().toString(),getActivity()).execute();

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}
        });
```

First I've wrote a EditorActionListener but it was not working and I've read that for several Android versions the editorlisteneer was never called.
In this Listener I call the class SearchClicked which is below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class SearchClicked extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
private String toSearch;
private Address address;
private Context c;

public SearchClicked(String toSearch, Context c) {
    this.toSearch = toSearch;
    this.c= c;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    try {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(c, Locale.UK);
        List<Address> results = geocoder.getFromLocationName(toSearch, 1);

        if (results.size() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        address = results.get(0);

        // Now do something with this GeoPoint:
        GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (address.getLatitude() * 1E6), (int) (address.getLongitude() * 1E6));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", "Something went wrong: ", e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

When i run it, it well loads, but when I try writing something on the edittext i have an error:

```
Could not find class 'com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint'
ATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.fabien.rh, PID: 26795
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
        at com.example.fabien.renthelper.SearchClicked.doInBackground(SearchClicked.java:40)
        at com.example.fabien.renthelper.SearchClicked.doInBackground(SearchClicked.java:16)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

```
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

On this topic, I've have potentially found a solution:
[Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)
But I don't find "Order and Export" in Android Studio, and I don't have "Android Private Libraries": when I look for Libraries in "Project Structure" all i have is this:

```
"support-annotations (com.android.support-annotations:22.2.1)
support-v4 (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1)
support-v13 (com.android.support-v13:22.2.1)
appcompat-v7 (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1)
design (com.android.design:22.2.1)
gridlayout-v7 (com.android.support.gridlayout-v7:22.2.1)
mediarouter-v7 (com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.1)
play-services (com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0)
play-service-wearable (com.google.android.gms:play-services_wearable:7.5.0)
cardview-v7 (com.android.support-cardview-v7:22.2.1)
palette-v7 (com.android.support-palette-v7:22.2.1)
[...]"
```

If you can help, thank you in advance! ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I see the question. You need to resolve problem with this: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how that code could compile and from the posted elements it's not 100% clear how you configured the build on android studio, but in any case, there is no GeoPoint in google maps API v2.

You should instead use LatLng object:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng

Comment: Thanks, it was what I was looking for! I didn't know that GeoPoint was not enabled any more!