# parse initialization is making the app crash

Tags: java, android, database, parse-platform

I am trying to use parse but parse told me to include the first code into the project to check if the data is transfered.... my app crashes...

I then followed a solution on stack overflow that explained how you have to initialize the parse in separate class and include it into manifest file... but after I followed it... my app still doesn't work... It crashes every single time..

**Android manifest**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.parseexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:name=".Initializeparse"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.parseexample;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        testObject.put("foo", "bar");
        testObject.saveInBackground();

    }


}
```

And this is my **parseexample.java**

```
    package com.example.parseexample;

    import com.parse.Parse;

    import android.app.Application;

    public class Initializeparse extends Application{

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate();

            Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());

            Parse.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "lUdLAC7d7HXQfdv1g7SO0T70jcc6vIMIHJRlYEvE", "ObFeYoJE3dqJmxMSfMkCQx37MvAqQfrNvnXHr38v");

        }



    }
```

**Logcat**

```
    08-14 05:07:48.569: D/HyLog(3996): I : /data/font/config/sfconfig.dat, No such file or directory (2)
08-14 05:07:48.569: D/HyLog(3996): I : /data/font/config/dfactpre.dat, No such file or directory (2)
08-14 05:07:48.569: D/HyLog(3996): I : /data/font/config/sfconfig.dat, No such file or directory (2)
08-14 05:07:48.579: I/dalvikvm(3996): Could not find method com.parse.Parse.initialize, referenced from method com.example.parseexample.Initializeparse.onCreate
08-14 05:07:48.579: W/dalvikvm(3996): VFY: unable to resolve static method 19: Lcom/parse/Parse;.initialize (Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
08-14 05:07:48.579: D/dalvikvm(3996): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0007
08-14 05:07:48.579: D/AndroidRuntime(3996): Shutting down VM
08-14 05:07:48.579: W/dalvikvm(3996): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a00e48)
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996): Process: com.example.parseexample, PID: 3996
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.Parse
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996):     at com.example.parseexample.Initializeparse.onCreate(Initializeparse.java:14)
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4432)
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:142)
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1263)
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5120)
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
08-14 05:07:48.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3996):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: crash -> stacktrace or get your question closed

Answer (score 1):

Add 'Initializeparse parseHelper = new Initializeparse();' in the onCreate method of MainActivity.

Comment: It would be great if you could 'Accept' the answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: My app still crashes. As parseHelper is never used.

Comment: Please tell me why is this happening.

Comment: Please add your stacktrace from the Logcat

Comment: Add the Parse SDK to your build path. Google for solving - NoClassDef error.You can also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774303/getting-error-in-using-parse-sdk-library-in-sample-android-app

Comment: i did add parse SDK to build path otherwise i would not have been able to even run the application as would get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this in your Initializeparse class.

```
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "lUdLAC7d7HXQfdv1g7SO0T70jcc6vIMIHJRlYEvE", "ObFeYoJE3dqJmxMSfMkCQx37MvAqQfrNvnXHr38v");
```

Comment: You added the library files(jar files), right? Logcat says it cannot find the parse methods.