# Java build path parse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parse-platform, buildpath

Trying to make Parse work on Android, but I'm having some problems with the build path while trying to upload some Data and/or trying to add a user to loggin. Probably something to do with the *.jar. Spent hours Trying to find a solution. In fact, tried most of the solutions on both these threads:

[Getting Error in using parse SDK library in sample Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774303/getting-error-in-using-parse-sdk-library-in-sample-android-app)

[Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

But none seem to work.

```
package com.testingparse;

import android.app.Application;
import android.net.ParseException;



import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

public class ChatApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(this, "ID#1", "ID#2");



    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    testObject.saveInBackground();
        }
    }
```

P.S.: ID#1 and ID#2 are actually the right numbers of my application at the Parse site at Settings>Keys of my application.

Any help at all would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

2 SS of the problem (notification and solution suggested by Eclipse):
http://imageshack.com/a/img673/4706/vjcgYK.png

http://imageshack.com/a/img909/7189/XiXc4R.png

Comment: What kind of problem? Compilation error? Do you have any logs? Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: @Mark Pazon - Posted a SS at the end of the edited post, Mark. It doesn't even compile, so no log generated. Also, using Eclipse. It's problably a configuration error, but like I said, none of the solutions on both threads I posted (with problems alike) worked for me. Thanks for the fast response, btw.

Comment: why don't you use android studio? eclipse is deprecated

Comment: Can you hover your mouse over the code that has problems and check the message? In your screenshot it seems that you have performed a "right click" already. Is your jar in the "libs" folder?

Comment: @Mat Pazon - Sorry, my bad. Added to the post the notification besides the solution proposed by Eclipse. But yeah, the *.jar is in the "libs" folder, and I right-clicked on the *.jar and added it to build path, also Android Private Libraries is checked.

Comment: @Mat Pazon - Turns out you were at the right track, Mat. Found the solution and posted down below. Thanks.